# Spotify iOS-SDK: Get Tracks from Playlist returns (null) Tracks

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, xcode, spotify

I would like to get Tracks from a selected Playlist with Spotify iOS SDK.
But it always return no items in my array.
I am using following code to fetch the tracks:

```
[SPTPlaylistSnapshot playlistWithURI:selectedPlaylist.uri accessToken:auth.session.accessToken callback:^(NSError *error, id object) {

    if (!error) {
        SPTPlaylistSnapshot *playlistSnapchot = object;

        NSArray *songItemsArray =  playlistSnapchot.firstTrackPage.items;
        NSLog(@"LOADED: %@", songItemsArray);

        [songItemsArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

            SPTPartialTrack *track = obj;
            NSLog(@"%@", track.name);


        }];

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error loading Playlist Tracks: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }

}];
```

Every time my *songsItemsArray* is **(null)**

Does any one know what is the reason for this problem?
I am using all Spotify Scopes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might come from the absence of a linker flag, add "-all_load" to Other Linker Flags in the Project.

I do this in my app, here's my code:

```
func getTracksFrom(page:SPTListPage, allItems:[SPTPlaylistTrack]) -> [SPTPlaylistTrack] {
    guard let items = page.items as? [SPTPlaylistTrack] else {print("empty page");return allItems}
    var allTracks = allItems
    allTracks.append(contentsOf: items)

    var nextPage = SPTListPage()

    if page.hasNextPage {
        page.requestNextPage(withAccessToken: (SPTAuth.defaultInstance().session.accessToken)!) { (error, data) in
            guard let p = data as? SPTListPage else {return}
            nextPage = p
        }

        return getTracksFrom(page:nextPage,allItems:allTracks)
    }
    return allTracks
}

func getAllTracksFrom(_ playlist:SPTPlaylistSnapshot) -> [SPTPlaylistTrack]  {
    var allTracks:[SPTPlaylistTrack] = []
    allTracks = getTracksFrom(page: playlist.firstTrackPage, allItems: allTracks)
    return allTracks
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    guard let p = playlist else {return}
    SPTPlaylistSnapshot.playlist(withURI: p.uri, accessToken: (SPTAuth.defaultInstance().session.accessToken)!, callback: { (error, dataOrNil) in
        guard error == nil else {print(error!);return}
        guard let playlistSnapshot = dataOrNil as? SPTPlaylistSnapshot else {print("couldn't cast as SPTPlaylistSnapshot");return}
        self.tracks = self.getAllTracksFrom(playlistSnapshot)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

Comment: unresolved identifier in viewdid load, p=playlist, will u please guide me